# Why Aren't FormControl#valueChanges' Subscriptions Garbage Collected?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I have gone through plenty of threads saying that one needs to unsubscribe from `FormControl#valueChanges` to prevent memory leaks. I understood the "when" and "how" to unsubscribe from `Observable`s. As I understand, Observables that produce *infinite* number of values need to be unsubscribed and `FormControl#valueChanges` is one such `Observable`.

But my question is, why aren't these `Observables`s garbage collected? I mean when an Angular component gets destroyed, the references are dead right? The form control in the template is no longer there. The `FormControl` instance is also gone. So if the "source" of the `Observable`, the `FormControl`, is gone then how come its member `valueChanges` still exist and retain its subscriptions?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I performed some experiments with the Memory Profiler in Chrome Dev Tools. What I found was, whether you unsubscribe from `FormControl#valueChanges` or the component gets destroyed the result is almost the same. In both cases one `SubjectSubscription` gets garbage collected. Take a look at the results below.

---

## When component gets destroyed

[image: List of some deleted objects when component got destroyed]

## When manually unsubscribed

[image: List of some deleted objects when Observable was unsubscribed]

So I think it's safe to say that the subscriptions do in fact get removed and one does not need to unsubscribe manually.